# Rails 3.2.8 insert or update based on condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am new to Rails and using this code to update or insert.

```
user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
if user.nil?
  User.create!(params)
else
  user.save(params)
end 

// params is a hash with keys as table columns
```

This code is not working. Also, I would like to know if Rails has something magical to do this in one line ?

I've not declared `email` as primary key but its going to be unique. Will it help me to declare it as primary ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because the parameter to `save` is as a hash of options (such as should validations run), not the changes to the attributes. You probably want `update_attributes!` instead. I would usually write something like

```
User.where(:email => params[:email]).first_or_initialize.update_attributes!(params)
```

Comment: Yes, I just noticed before your answer that `save` does not take attributes as arguments. Can you share a resource where can I find a short summary/docs of rails methods ?

Comment: Your answer works fine. What does `first_or_initialize` do here ?

Comment: apidock.com is ok. first_or_initialize returns either the first matching row or a new instance of user

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])  # if you receive email in params[:email]
unless user.present?
  @user = User.create!(params[:user]) # params[:user] replace with whatever you receive all your attributes 
else
  @user = user # here if your want to update something you can do it by using update attributes
end
```